# Calling EJBRemoteBean method from Servlet

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb-3.0, remote-access

Is it possible to class an EJBRemoteBean from a servlet which is placed in another project please ?
And how ? I've tried this

**1st project;**

EJBRemoteBean.java

```
@Stateless
public class EJBRemoteBean implements EJBRemote {

    @Override
    public int addition( int x, int y ) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

EJBRemote.java

```
@Remote
public interface EJBRemote {
    public int addition( int x, int y );
}
```

**2nd project:**

EJBServlet.java

```
public class EJBServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB( mappedName = "com.ejb.session.stateless.EJBRemote" )
    private EJBRemote ejbr;

    protected void processRequest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType( "text/html;charset=UTF-8" );
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<html>" );
        out.println( "<head>" );
        out.println( "<title>Servlet EJBServlet</title>" );
        out.println( "</head>" );
        out.println( "<body>" );
        out.println( "<h1>EJBRemote.addition returned: " + ejbr.addition( 2, 3 ) + "</h1>" );
        out.println( "</body>" );
        out.println( "</html>" );
    }

    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest( request, response );
    }

    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest( request, response );
    }
}
```

I can't find how to fix this servlet to call the contained method of EJBRemoteBean. Any help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say "insert a call to ejbr.addition(...) in your processRequest method", but that seems obvious.  Did you try that, and if so, what happened?

Comment: how can I deal that, please ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to answer that question because you're not giving enough information.